# нужна помощь с задачей Python с нахождением 2 макс чисел

Tags: python

есть список в который вводят последовательность чисел, далее программа отбирает среди них два наибольших натуральных числа, и находит их произведение. Так же последовательность чисел заканчивается 0 ( но не входит в саму последовательность ). Не знаю как решить проблему с нулем, и как сделать код правильнее и эстетичнее

написал что то похожее: )

```
print ("Введите числа через пробел: ")
a = [int(value) for value in input().split()]
a.sort()
a = a[-2] * a[-1]
print(a)
```

Comment: Добавьте в конце однострочника в квадратные скобки `if value != 0`, а потом к конечному списку припишите ноль.

Comment: Вероятно, в учебной задаче предлагали вводить числа по одному, пока не будет введен 0. Ввод написан в ответе @Mbo.  А поиск наибольших и произведение нормально в общем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Красота в функциональности. Отдельный генератор читает целые числа (`ints`). Отдельная функция выделяет пару максимальных чисел (`max_pair`) (для этого есть метод [heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), но я решил написать всё руками). Отдельная функция собирает всё вместе (`main`).

Хранить все числа нет смысла, `max_pair` хранит только старшую пару.

```
def ints():
    """ читает входной поток и выдаёт целые числа до первого нуля """
    while True:
        for x in map(int, input().split()):
            if x == 0:
                return
            yield x


def max_pair(seq):
    """ выделяет пару самых больших чисел из последовательности """
    max_pair = []
    for x in seq:
        max_pair.append(x)
        if len(max_pair) > 2:
            max_pair.sort(reverse=True)
            max_pair.pop()
    return max_pair


def main():
    """ печатает произведение пары самых больших чисел из входного потока """
    a, b = max_pair(ints())
    print(a * b)


main()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли )

Answer (score 0):

Про ноль обычно имеется в виду следующее:

```
a = []
while t:=int(input()):
    a.append(t)
print(a)
```

---

```
1
3
0
[1, 3]
```

Comment: в данном случае код будет добавлять в список введенные числа, пока не наткнется на ноль, это не совсем то что нужно, но все равно спасибо

Comment: Это как раз довольно стандартный подход при вводе заранее неизвестного количества чисел в учебных задачах.

Comment: согласен что код подходит, осталось отобрать 2 наибольших числа из списка и умножить их друг на друга, проблема больше в учителе, которая не разрешает писать программу подобным образом(((

Comment: А что именно запрещено? Здесь использован довольно новый оператор `:=`, который позволяет сократить код, но без него можно обойтись